# Issue with NgForm Controls arrange in alphabetical order Angular

Tags: angular, angular11

I have a function formErrorMessage which will loop through the form controls in NgForm and check if it has error and append the error message to an array. However, the error message is not arrange in the order same as my form because the form control is arrange in alphabetical order.

```
formErrorMessage(formControls : { [key: string]: AbstractControl; }){

    var aryErrors: Array<{ [key: string] : string }> = [];
    
    //loop tru the controls
    Object.keys(formControls).forEach(key => {

        //if has errors
        var objErrors = formControls[key].errors;
        var formObj = key;

        if(objErrors){
            
            //loop tru the errors
            Object.keys(objErrors).forEach(key => {
                //retrive the relevant message from ValidationFormsService
                aryErrors[formObj] = this.vf.errorMessages[formObj][key];
            });
        
        }
    });

    return aryErrors;
}//end formErrorMessage
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: take a look to https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know that Objects do not know the order of the NgForm controls so I created an array of the form fields and loop through the array and check against NgForm errors in order to retain the form field arrangement.

In the service

```
public aryFormFields : Array<{[key : string] : any}> = [
{"membID" : ''},
{"salutation": ''},
{'name': ''},
{'referralSource': ''},
{'referralID': ''},
{'mobileNo': ''},
{'email': ''},
{'addr1': ''},
{'addr2': ''},
{'addr3': ''},
{'postalCode': ''},
{'membType': ''},
{'startDate': ''},
{'endDate': ''},
{'entitleCredit': ''},
{'lastCreditUseDate': ''},
{'lastCreditUseAmt': ''},
{'totalCreditBalance': ''},
{'serviceAdvisorID': ''},
{'pdpaConcern': ''},
{'pdpaSMS': ''},
{'pdpaEmail': ''},
{'pdpaPhone': ''},
```

];

In form validation function

```
const formFields = this.memberService.aryFormFields;

    let aryErrors: Array<{[key : string] : any}> = [];

    for(var i =0; i < formFields.length; i++){

        //loop tru the empty aryErrors
        Object.keys(formFields[i]).forEach(key=> {
            var objErrors = formControls[key].errors;
            var formObj = key;

            //if has error
            if (objErrors) {
                //loop tru the errors
                Object.keys(objErrors).forEach(key => {
                    
                    //retrive the relevant message from ValidationFormsService                        
                    if (this.vf.errorMessages.hasOwnProperty(formObj)) {
                        aryErrors[i]={ [formObj] : this.vf.errorMessages[formObj][key]};
                    }
                    else {
                        //if not exist, using formObj
                        aryErrors[i]={ [formObj] : this.toCamelCase(formObj) + " is "+ key +"!"};
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }//for 
    
    return aryErrors;
```